# How can I send a message to property validator İsvalid in fluentvalidation?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, fluentvalidation

hello fluent validation has been updated to version 10.3.6 but the SetMessage function that was in the properyvalidator that was working before does not work anymore, what should I use instead?

```
    public class TcknOrVknPropValidator : PropertyValidator
    {
        public TcknOrVknPropValidator() : base()
        {

        }

        protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
        {
            var propertyValue = context.PropertyValue as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyValue))
            {
                SetErrorMessage("Tc veya Vergi No Geçersiz");//this function not found now
               
                return false;
            }

            if (propertyValue.Length < 10 || propertyValue.Length > 11)
            {

                SetErrorMessage("Tc Veya Vergi No Eksik Yada Hatalı");
                return false;
            }

           return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new version, it has a usage as follows

```
public class VisitIdValidator<T, TCollectionElement> : PropertyValidator<T, TCollectionElement>
{

    public VisitIdValidator()
    {

    }

    public override bool IsValid(ValidationContext<T> context, TCollectionElement visitId)
    {
        if (visitId==null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(visitId.ToString()))
        {
            context.MessageFormatter.AppendArgument("NotNull", visitId);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public override string Name => "ListCountValidator";

    protected override string GetDefaultMessageTemplate(string errorCode)
        => "{PropertyName} notnull";
}
```

use of

```
 RuleFor(x => x.VisitId).SetValidator(new VisitIdValidator<SavePhoneRequestModel,string>());
```